# Why is the workload rate on WD Red Pro drives so low?

Tags: hard-drive

[A top-of-the-line WD Red Pro 22 TB drive currently has a workload rating of 300 TB a year.](https://www.westerndigital.com/products/internal-drives/wd-red-pro-sata-hdd#WD221KFGX). 300 TB / 22 TB = 13.6x. That means if you write the Hard Drive full on January 1, you can only read it back once a month for the year? This seems really low.

Why are hard drives so fragile these days? What contributes to them having such a low workload?

Comment: If you want high workload drives, you need to spend the extra green to buy high workload drives

Comment: In the first place, is “workload rate” even a scientific measurement? Is it something to rely on/work with? Or is it just marketing? This is the first time I hear this term.

Comment: @DanielB is it a scientific measurement? Sure. You stress test the drive and the result creates the MTBF, but the MTBF has to have a stated workload rating to be useful. You grind the drive with 0-downtime, you'll far exceed the MTBF. And you'll also probably flag over the workload rating when you send the drive in for warranty.

Comment: Maybe integrated NAND wears out at that time.